# Android app force closing after adding Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, splash-screen

Hi i made a project which was running great before i started adding this Splash Screen to my project.  I don't understand why when I run it in the emulator it force closes.

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.acrcloud.rec.demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PageActivity"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

This is my SplashScreen.java ,and XML file name splash_screen.xml

```
package com.acrcloud.rec.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
public class SplashScreen extends Activity{
private static int splashInterval = 2000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            this.finish();

        }
     private void finish(){
         //TODO Auto
     }
    },splashInterval);
};
}
```

LogCat Error:`

```
10-13 13:14:33.068 12422-12422/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.acrcloud.rec.demo, PID: 12422
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to startactivityComponentInfo{com.acrcloud.rec.demo/com.acrcloud.rec.demo.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
at com.acrcloud.rec.demo.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:12)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share xml com.acrcloud.rec.demo.SplashScreen

Comment: there is an issue with your `xml` of `SplashScreen` kindly post its layout here

Comment: Add your splash xml

Comment: I added a splash screen.xml.          Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
- After adding new screen may be application need to clean and re-build.
- Run the application on device not emulator and feedback me if the same result is happen.

Comment: I'm doing clean and re-build project. Then run the application on device again. But it show the same result.  (Unfortunately,Myapp has stopped.)